# Dragging a div with jQuery causes page to be highlighted

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Please refer to my [prior question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786301/drag-and-drop-divs-across-page) about implementing drag/drop. I got everything working fine, but now when I drag one of the list items, it also highlights practically everything on the page. With the answer from this prior question, how do I make it so it does not highlight anything while dragging? My actual code is 3 different files and is far different (much more) than the sample in the accepted answer, so I will post it only if necessary.

This is using jQuery's capabilities via `draggable` and `droppable` elements. This functionality is implemented like so (things renamed and shortened):

```
    $(function () {
        InitMySystem();
        $("#MyList li").draggable({ revert: true });
        $("#MyDropBox").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                HandleDrop(selIndex, 0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you looked at [CSS user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/user-select)? It's not standard yet, but it could help you nail the issue in most browsers.

Comment: @zi42 Yes, that worked, I put: `-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none;` in the body style and that took care of it.

Comment: Done. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [CSS user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/user-select)? It's not standard yet, but it could help you nail the issue in most browsers.